# Twitter API Keys, Secrets, and Tokens

Tags: twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

It looks like Twitter changed terminology over the years and did not update their docs appropriately, which leads to confusion (at least on my part).

According to https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request I need to use `oauth_consumer_key` and `oauth_token`.

At this time I want to access the account that is owned by the website that is making the request, so I am not trying to get a token for a website user, but instead use the tokens provided by Twitter for the Application.

In the Application details page, I have values for `API key`, `API secret`, `Access token`, and `Access token secret`

Can you tell me how these keys/secrets map to the `oauth_consumer_key` and `oauth_token`?  And what are the other two used for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

It looks like `Consumer` maps to `API` and `Access Token` maps to `OAuth Token`, so to clarify:

`oauth_consumer_key` : API Key

`oauth_token` : Access Token

`Consumer secret` : API Secret

`OAuth token secret` : Access Token Secret